# How inefficient is it to execute a jar inside a loop? What are the alternatives?

Tags: java, c++, loops, memory, jar

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use both JAVA and C++. The JAVA part is responsible for printing to stdout a string that depends on the arguments passed to the main method with a method call (say getString()). But first, it needs to create multiple objects.

Currently, my C++ program creates a console and repeatedly executes the compiled JAVA program within an infinite loop to refresh the printed output on the console.

While this is a relatively small program, its efficiency and memory usage worries me as the C++ program continuously executes the jar file that consequently creates and destroys new objects each time.

I think that ideally, the C++ program should execute the JAVA program once and only call getString() at each iteration to limit all the objects instantiation to only once instead of every iteration.

That being said, I was wondering if that would make a difference and if so, is it doable? How?

Comment: JNI allows you to start up the JVM once and call it over and over.

Comment: Load the jar in a JNI JVM. Instantiate the object and convert from a local ref to global ref, free the local ref. In the loop, call getString() on the globalRef of the object. At the end of the loop free the global ref.

Comment: On a scale of 1 to 10 where 10 is the most inefficient, I'd say your approach is around 8.

Comment: Alternatives:  1) Use JNI to start the Java and call methods as suggested above, 2) turn the Java app into a RESTful server, 3) turn the Java app into something that your C++ can talk to over a pipe or a socket, 4) recode the Java in C++, 5) recode the C++ in Java.  And probably more.